Prove that $f$ doesn't attain its local maximum

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is of class $C^3$ s.t
$$\Delta f=\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2}+\dfrac{\partial
 ^2f}{\partial y^2}>0\quad\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2.$$ Prove that
$f$ doesn't attain its local maximum.

Assume $f$ attains its local maximum at $a$.
I think we need to consider the Hessian matrix of $f$:
$$H(a)=\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2}(a) & \dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(a)\\\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(a) & \dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial y^2}(a)\end{pmatrix}$$
One thing I knew that if $\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2}(x_0,y_0)<0$ and $\begin{vmatrix} \dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2}(x_0,y_0) & \dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\\\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(x_0,y_0) & \dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial y^2}(x_0,y_0)\end{vmatrix}>0$ then $f$ attains its local maximum at $(x_0,y_0)$. From hypothesis, we deduce that Trace $H(a)>0$.
I don't know whether it leads to any contradiction or not. I don't know how to continue though. I would be very appreciated if someone can continue this path or have other ways to deal with this problem. Thanks in advance!

At a local maximum is $\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2}(x_0,y_0) \le 0$ and ... ? Therefore ... ?

It is unsure, may be even wrong about $\Leftarrow$ direction, which is: "If $f$ attains it local maximum at $(x_0,y_0)$ then $\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2}(x_0,y_0)<0$ and $\begin{vmatrix} \dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2}(x_0,y_0) & \dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\\dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(x_0,y_0) & \dfrac{\partial ^2f}{\partial y^2}(x_0,y_0)\end{vmatrix}>0$

with $\leq$ it is true, not wrong

Sorry, I don't what you mean. I would be much appreciated if someone could write down the explanation in the answering section down below so that I can understand better.

If $f(x,y)$ admits a local maximum at $(x_0,y_0)$ then $x\mapsto f(x,y_0)$ and $y\mapsto f(x_0,y)$ admit local maxima at $x_0$ and $y_0,$ respectively.

As @RyszardSzwarc pointed out in his comment, if there was a point $(x_0,y_0)$ in which the function has a local maximum, then the two functions of one variable
$$
g(x) = f(x,y_0), \qquad h(y) = f(x_0,y)
$$
should have a local maximum in $x_0$ and in $y_0$, respectively.
This means that their second derivatives are negative or zero in the maximum
$$
g''(x_0) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x_0,y_0) \leq 0 \\
h''(y_0) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x_0,y_0) \leq 0
$$
and this is in clearly in contrast with $\Delta f(x,y)  >0.$

Very clear! I read it smoothly without any confusion. Thanks!
